# Restrict SDC agent connections to Restlet SDC server

Tags: restlet, restlet-2.0

What is the prescribed method to restrict connections to the Restlet tunnel server from SDC agents?

Assume an agent was configured to connect to a tunnel server and The connection parameters were provided. It is possible that later we may not want to allow the SDC agent connect any more.  How do we restrict these connections on the SDC tunnel server from the specified agents?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend IP filtering at the firewall level for now. In version 2.2, we could add support for some additional control at the Restlet SDC level. Opportunity for contributions...

Feel free to enter an issue in GitHub.

Comment: Maintaining a list of IPs at the firewall level is difficult to scale.  For now we added some code to the server to read IPs from a database and filter them.  Will enter a request on GitHub.